# List of Lists to 2D Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, ironpython, excel-interop

I have a list of lists in Python that holds a mix of values, some are strings and some are tuples.

```
data = [[0,1,2],["a", "b", "c"]]
```

I am wondering if there is a way to easily convert any length list like that to a 2D Array without using Numpy. I am working with System.Array because that's the format required. 
I understand that I can create a new instance of an Array and then use for loops to write all data from list to it. I was just curious if there is a nice Pythonic way of doing that.

```
x = len(data)
y = len(data[0])
arr = Array.CreateInstance(object, x, y)
```

Then I can loop through my data and set the arr values right?

```
arr = Array.CreateInstance(object, x, y)
for i in range(0, len(data),1):
    for j in range(0,len(data[0]), 1):
        arr.SetValue(data[i][j], i,j)
```

I want to avoid looping like that if possible. Thank you,

Ps. This is for Excel Interop where I can set a whole Range in Excel by setting it to be equal to an Array. That's why I want to convert a list to an Array. Thank you,

Thing that I am wondering about is that Array is a typed object, is it possible to set its constituents to either string or integer? I think i might be constrained to only one. Right? If so, is there any other type of data that I can use? 
Is setting it to Arrayobject ensures that I can combine str/int inside of it?

Also I though I could use this:

```
arr= Array[Array[object]](map(object, data))
```

but it throws an error. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use `Array.CreateInstance` to create 2D arrays, and they have to be of a single type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Array.CreateInstance(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a single, or multidimensional, array. Since the Array.CreateInstance method takes in a "Type" you specify any type you want. For example:

```
// gives you an array of string
myArrayOfString = Array.CreateInstance(String, 3)

// gives you an array of integer
myArrayOfInteger = Array.CreateInstance(Int32, 3)

// gives you a multidimensional array of strings and integer
myArrayOfStringAndInteger = [myArrayOfString, myArrayOfInteger]
```

Hope this helps. Also see the msdn website for examples of how to use Array.CreateInstance.